# JavaScript Function working well on Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that changes color of nav bar on click of button. I used a validator and it returned no errors.I used the validator on both browsers. Here is the part of the code, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<body class ="backgroundTwo">
        <h1 class ="centered sansSerif background" >Hello World!</h1>
        <div>
            <ul class ="center">
                <li class ="center"><a id="demo" class ="center"        href="about.html" >About This Site</a></li>
               <li class ="center"><a id ="demo2" class="center" href="current.html">Current Work</a></li>
               <li class ="center"><a id ="demo3" class="center" href="http://www.dallascowboys.com/">Cowboys</a><li>

            </ul> 
        </div>

        <h1 class = "centered" > <img src ="image.jpg" alt = "Cowboys" style="width:304px;height:228px;"></h1>
        <p class = "centered sansSerifTwo" >This is lrodrig6's CSC412 WebSite Project</p>
        <div class ="wrapper">
            <button class="button" onclick="colorFunction()">click    me</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            function colorFunction(){
             var color3 = document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor;
             var color2 = document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor;
             var color  = document.getElementById("demo3").style.backgroundColor;

                if (color === "lightblue" && color2 === "lightblue" && color3 === "lightblue"){
                    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                  document.getElementById("demo3").style.backgroundColor = "white";
            } else {
                    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                document.getElementById("demo3").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
               }
        }    
       </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just log `document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor` and see what the actual value is. It certainly isn’t `"lightblue"` in Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set a style attribute of an element (e.g. `style.backgroundColor`) to `"lightblue"` you cannot expect to read it back as `"lightblue"`.

For example chrome returns `"rgb(173, 216, 230)"` instead.

You need to keep a variable to store the current state instead of relying on reading back style attributes.

Reading and writing attributes of `style` is not like accessing regular members of a Javascript object. Those operations are equivalent to calls to `getPropertyValue` and `setProperty` and you have no guarantees that the value you pass when setting will be the same that you get back when retrieving.

For example it's also possible that passing `"rgb(1,2,3)"` you get back `"rgb(1, 2, 3)"` (with spaces). This is moreover absolutely evident if you set an attribute to something invalid (you will never read something invalid out of a property).

If you need to store logical state in an HTML element you can use the [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) that were introduced exactly for this usage.

In your specific case for example I'd write something like:

```
var color = "lightblue"; // Using a regular variable to store status

function colorFunction(){
    // Toggle color
    color = (color === "lightblue") ? "white" : "lightblue";
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById("demo3").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Comment: `you cannot expect to read it back as "lightblue".` - to be clear, you can in other browsers, just not chrome

Comment: Then why on chrome does it change from white to lightblue ? The function is suposed to switch it back from white to lightblue with each click, which it does do on firefox. On chrome it just stays stuck on lightblue after the first click and stays the same after the second click

Comment: From what I have been reading from all your answers which I appreciate very much. Would it be safe to just use values in the future ?

Comment: @JaromandaX: accessing a `style` object and reading/writing its members is not like reading/writing the members of a standard Javascript object, but they are equivalent to calls to `getPropertyValue` and `setProperty`. There are no guarantees that the value you get back when reading is the same that you passed when writing (this is absolutely evident for example if you set to something invalid).

Comment: @lrod408: no. If you write "rgb(255, 0, 0)" it's in theory possible that you will read back "red" (even if unlikely). Never read back from style attributes assuming the strings are the same that you put in... this is not guaranteed. Keep a separate variable (or a `data` attribute) for the state instead...

Comment: @6502, thanks for the info. I think I get what you are saying and will look into to it because I want to really understand this. So even though my code worked after changing to values, the way I'm using javascript is wrong ? Therefore the way I coded the function in incorrect ? Id rather have correct working function than an incorrect working function.

Comment: @6502 now I really understand thanks for the data attributes link. Clarifies it a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: @6502 thanks for the explanation of why chrome behaves differently to other browsers.

Comment: @6502 thanks you your patience and detailed explanation. The reason for storing the info in a variable makes much more sense now after looking at your code. Its just like in java or any other oop language.....how can I be so blind...lol. Thanks again sir.

Answer (score 1):

I donot believe this is the right way to do, but you can just replace the `lightblue` with `rgb(173, 216, 230)` for a quick solution

like this

```
function colorFunction(){
         var color3 = document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor;
         var color2 = document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor;
         console.log(color2);
         var color  = document.getElementById("demo3").style.backgroundColor;

            if (color === "rgb(173, 216, 230)" && color2 === "rgb(173, 216, 230)" && color3 === "rgb(173, 216, 230)"){
                document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
              document.getElementById("demo3").style.backgroundColor = "white";
        } else {
                document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(173, 216, 230)";
            document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(173, 216, 230)";
            document.getElementById("demo3").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(173, 216, 230)";
           }
    }
```

Comment: I did your suggestion and now it works fine on chrome but not firefox.

Comment: I just changed all the strings to values and it worked on both browsers.

Comment: @lrod408: you can't be sure things will work on other browsers. You should not read back from a style property and assume it will be the same exact string you put in it. Properties are not storage you can put what you want in it... they are not just members of a javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using "style.backgroundColor" would be to use

```
document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute("style", "background-color: lightblue";
```

That may yield a more reliable response.